# Hive query to convert date-time-stamp to date format

Tags: sql, mysql, hive, format

I want to convert a date-timestamp column containing values like '4/12/2023 15:37' into date format as: 2023-12-04 using hive query.
The to_date format gives me only null values.

Comment: Try  to_date(from_unixtime(timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'))

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to timestamp using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, then `FROM_UNIXTIME` will convert the number of seconds from unix epoch to string timestamp, `TO_DATE` will convert the timestamp to date. [Check Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#:%7E:text=non%2Dempty%20string.-,Date%20Functions,The%20following%20built%2Din%20date%20functions%20are%20supported%20in%20Hive%3A,-Return%20Type)

```
SELECT TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('04/12/2023 15:37', 'd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')));
```